# Azure Data Factory Rest API Pagination Call all pages

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-rest-api

I am new to ADF and I am trying to call a Rest API that is paginated. I have my base url in my dataset as https://*mydomain*.syncromsp.com/api/v1/tickets?api_key=*key_value*.

I am able to return the first page as seen in the image below. In the meta portion of the JSON it shows "total_pages: 51" and "page:1"

How do I return the rest of the of the pages? I am not sure what Pagination rules to use in my Source settings.

[image: First Page Returned]

Answer (score 0):

Your API response should contain the property of the next page `URL` to use the pagination to return to the next page.

You can follow this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) for more information on supported patterns of pagination in Rest API with examples.

Comment: I already checked the documentation and there is no info for this. All I have is the current page and total pages in the meta data. My guess is I need to use this as a parameter and increment until it reaches the total pages number but not sure how I would do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to pass the page item as a parameter in a loop and loop until the page = total pages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).